# Can i use quick controls in a qt widgets application?

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2, qtwidgets

I need material styled replacements of standard widgets and it's kind of hard to implement them by using custom widgets. I was wondering if there's any way to include widgets from quick control module and use them as regular widgets?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your application is Qt5.1 and above, the answer is yes you can.

You have to use the `QQuickView` object and pass it to static function `createWindowContainer` of `QWidget`, which takes `QWindow` as in paramater.

`QQuickView` derived from `QQuickWindow` which is derived from `QWindow`.

So you can pass a `QQuickView` as an input to the `createWindowContainer`.

Below is some rough code.

```
//CREATE A QQuickView  OBJECT.
QQuickView *view = new QQuickView();

//ADD THE QQuickView  OBJECT TO QWidget::createWindowContainer
QWidget *container = QWidget::createWindowContainer(view, this);

//ADD SOURCE
view->setSource(QUrl("your.qml"));

//ADD THE CONTAINER TO YOUR LAYOUT.
ui->verticalLayout->addWidget(container);
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`QQuickWidget`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qquickwidget.html) if you want to insert your QML view in a layout :

```
//CREATE THE QQuickWidget
QQuickWidget *quickWidget = new QQuickWidget(this);

//ADD SOURCE
view->setSource(QUrl("your.qml"));

//ADD THE QQuickWidget TO YOUR LAYOUT.
ui->verticalLayout->addWidget(quickWidget);
```

I adapted @katamarayudu's code to use `QQuickWidget` instead of `QQuickView`.